# playframeworkのAPIのプログラムを実行したい

Tags: java, api, playframework, intellij-idea

現在Java,playframework2.8,intelliJでかんたんなAPIプログラムを作っています。
以下を参考にして作ったのですが、これを実行するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？
routesファイルにURIとリクエストメソッドとコントローラのメソッド名を記述し、そのURIをブラウザで叩く。これだと足りないし、違うような気もします。
もしわかる方がいれば教えて下さい
https://qiita.com/kunst1080/items/ab172539b0e7abc8e97f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

routesに以下を記載してマッピングし、

```
GET     /hoge                       controllers.HogeController.index
```

intelliJのターミナルから`sbt run`でWebサーバーを実行し、

ブラウザで以下へアクセスすると
http://localhost:9000/hoge

intelliJのターミナルに以下の期待値を出力することができました！

```
before action
--------------------------
HogeController.index
--------------------------
status:200
after action
```

---

Macのターミナルから以下のcurlコマンドを叩いてもintelliJのターミナルに出力することができました。

```
curl http://localhost:9000/hoge
```

Comment: play run でなく sbt runであったというところがポイントでした。
参考：https://qiita.com/ka2kama/items/6804d80936cd92b2405c

Comment: 停止はintelliJのターミナル上でCtrl+C